# Why my css styles fall apart when I open nextjs app?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I have a material ui bottom navigation component and when my app loads the component it sticks to  (what is even that I can't find it in global css files)

However I don't think there is anything wrong with my code, because as soon as I click on navigation buttons the styles are **working properly** and navigation goes back to the bottom.

here is my css:

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: max-content;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}
```

and bottom nav:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    position: "fixed",
    bottom: 0,
  },
});
```

Also I've had problems with **not modified** material ui textfield components, when I open the page sometimes the input field is completely distorted and sometimes it works properly. Why is this happening?

Here is the illustration of the issues:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your actual code?

Comment: What do your `_document` and `_app` pages look like? I'd recommend following the [official Next.js example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs) from Material UI repo.